# How to send a number in query string with axios

Tags: javascript, axios, encoding, parameters, numbers

My react application call an API to post with query string.

For example,

```
var param = {

  name: 'Alex',
  age: 22
}

axios({
    baseURL: 'https://aaa.com',
    url: '/user/create', 
    method: 'post', 
    params: param,
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${_token}`
    },
})
```

This works fine.  But, the value of age was inserted as string. like this "22".
All of numbers in parameters were inserted as string.

I tried to use "qs".

```
axios.defaults.paramsSerializer = params => {

    var paramStr = qs.stringify(params)

    return paramStr
}
```

But the result was same.

Do I need to use other encoding tech for query string ?

Ahh, When I call the same API on the Swagger,  it works fine.

On the swagger, the call looks like this.

```
    curl -X 'POST' \
  'https://aaa.com:82000/some/create?subtype=time_event&title=%EC%A0%9C%EB%AA%A9&content=%7B%0A%20%20%22intactive%22%3A%20true%2C%0A%20%20%20%22startTimeHour%22%20%3A%2012%2C%0A%20%20%20%22startTimeMinute%22%3A%200%2C%0A%20%20%20%22endTimeHour%22%3A%2019%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22endTimeMinute%22%3A%200%2C%0A%20%20%22list%22%3A%20%5B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22lang%22%20%3A%20%22ko%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22title%22%20%3A%20%22%EC%A0%9C%EB%AA%A9%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22content%22%20%3A%20%22ss%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%5D%0A%7D&rewards=%7B%7D&startDate=2023-07-20T13%3A00%3A00Z&endDate=2023-07-20T15%3A45%3A00Z' \
  -H 'accept: application/json' \
  -H 'Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJfaWQiOiJ5c2tpbSIsImdyYWRlIjoiTWFpbiIsImlhdCI6MTY5OTI3MTU4MiwiZXhwIjoxNjk5ODc2MzgyfQ.Od2y--LBhOxHzPu9tJgQ0M3y2X7TWaMtT2Pj66tP_g8' \
  -d ''
```

Comment: The fact that `query strings` are a **String**, you always send a string ... the server needs to be smarter

Comment: @Jaromanda  Thank you for comments.  But When I try to the work "post to the API with query string" , it works fine.   it's so weird.

Comment: No idea what `When I try to the work "post to the API with query string"` is trying to say

Comment: @JaromandaX  Thank you for your interest.   What I wanted to say is  when I called the same API with same query string in swagger it works fine.  
( All of number data was inserted as number. ). But when I try it with my codes,  all of numbers in the params is inserted as string.

Answer (score -1):

You can use below code to efficiently send data to server using axios:

```
const { data } = await axios.post( 
        `${server}/users/login`,
        {
          // Put your all params here with query
        },
        {
          headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "Authorization": `Bearer ${_token}`
          },
          withCredentials: true,
        }
      ).then( (response) => {
        console.log(response);
      })
      .catch( (error) => {
        console.log("Axios Error: " + error.message);
      });
```

Comment: Could you explain more, please? 

"//Put your all params hear with query"

--> How can I add my params in there?  Like this?
   {
      param: params
   }

Comment: this is completely different code to the code in the question

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).